# Roasting vegetables that have been cut on raw bacon board? Safe or not?

Tags: raw

I cut raw peppers on the same board that I cut raw bacon on. I will be roasting these at 585F (305°C). Should I be concerned about contamination?

Comment: 585F?  You should be worried about them catching fire.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by "raw" bacon? 
In a lot of with world bacon is only available cured and smoked -- in which case see [this question (If you are unsure see that question also. There is some debate about this.)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/is-it-safe-to-eat-smoked-bacon-without-grilling).
The bacon itself is probably safe to eat without further cooking, and the peppers certainly.

On the other hand some people in some places (the British(?)) have this thing for unsmoked bacon which is basically just raw meat.
In which case you have contaminated the peppers.
But it doesn't matter because you are cooking them anyway.
And any contaminants are probably not going to have time to multiply, and produce non-heat destructed toxins between last night and when you cook them.
(If not you probably have other problems, like the bacon already being spoiled)

Comment: American grocery store bacon is basically raw. It has been brined with liquid smoke flavor. I wouldn't eat raw vegetables that had been chopped on it, just because it's difficult to clean so much surface area properly, especially the cut surfaces.

Comment: While I appreciate that in some places "bacon" is something you can eat without cooking, as Joshua has pointed out, there are a lot of places where that definitely *isn't* true. So given that this is a global site, it's probably best to avoid making statements like "The bacon itself is probably safe to eat without further cooking." I know you sort of explained/qualified, but it's even better to avoid possibly misleading people. (Also the OP used Fahrenheit, so they're most likely from the US, and what you're saying wouldn't apply for them.)

Comment: @JoshuaEngel sure, that is why I linked to the question that fully discusses that. I'm not going to repeat an entire question in my post. Assuming it is cured+smoked then that question applies (from which the current accepted answer is safe to eat, but which certainly debate exists.)

Comment: @Jefromi I respectfully disagree. My "sort of explained/qualified" is infact an explanation. To do otherwise would be a disservice to the answer, making it less complete. It begins by asking the asker to consider if their bacon is "raw" or "cured and smoked". Then the majority of the answer is concerned with the "unsmoked bacon which is basically just raw meat."

Comment: Keep in mind, this is about making it as easy as possible for the OP and future readers to fully understand everything. So: there's a big difference between "The bacon is safe to eat" and "If your bacon is smoked/cured, then it's safe to eat." And it's also good to focus on what will help the OP first. We know the OP is American, and almost certainly has bacon that requires cooking, so it may be more helpful to lead with that part of the answer, and then mention cured bacon afterwards. Note that I'm not asking for drastic changes, just suggesting tweaking phrasing and order.

Comment: But if I take that bacon, and cook it in the oven, I can eat it, right?  What is magical about bacon residue that it would be immune to cooking in the oven after touching vegetables?  When I make fajitas, the chicken and veggies all marinade together (about 1/2 of the marinade is lime juice), and then the vegetables are thoroughly cooked.  If cooking makes the bacon or the chicken suitable to eat, shouldn't that same cooking also take care of vegetables? This does not disagree with the answer, at all, but more about asking why it is so vital to be clear about "raw" bacon or not, for this case.

Comment: I had not intended my incidental comment about raw vegetables to disagree with that aspect of the answer: cross-contamination isn't a concern if you're cooking. I was just clarifying that for an important segment of the audience (e.g. Americans), using tools that had touched uncooked bacon with vegetables would be considered cross-contamination. The vegetables are safe when cooked but not raw.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel - Thank you for clarifying. I clearly misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a big deal, it would still be safe to eat the vegetables raw, you'd just need to wash them thoroughly. You do not need to worry about contamination of the cooked food as cooking it will kill off any possible pathogens, even if you don't wash them first. It will be perfectly safe to eat. You do need to be aware that anything the uncooked vegetables came in contact with after they were cut might have a bit of bacon on it, in which case you just need to clean it.